# IPB php function works but is slow. SQL needs to be faster

Tags: php, sql, performance, function, ipb

I'm only using a small part of this function actually but I wanted to post it all to provide the big picture. There is a part of the query in this function that finds recent attachments a user has posted to the forums. The block is on the user profile. IT works but the problem is ... it's VERY slow!! Core attachments locks up for 30+ seconds and makes my site unusable.

Any one who could help it would be much appreciated.

```
   private function getAttImages($limit, $forumIds = 0, $fidsReverse = false, $topicIds = 0, $membersIds = 0, $order = 'attach_date', $sort = 'desc', $group = null)
        {
            $fids = '';

            if ($forumIds)
            {
                $r = '';
                if ($fidsReverse)
                {
                    $r = ' NOT ';
                }

                if (is_array($forumIds))
                {
                    $forumIds = implode(',', $forumIds);
                }

                $fids = ' AND forums_topics.forum_id ' . $r . ' IN (' . $forumIds .  ')';
            }

            $tids = '';
            if ($topicIds)
            {
                $tids = ' AND forums_topics.tid IN (' . $topicIds . ')';
            }

            $mids = '';
            if ($membersIds)
            {
                $mids = ' AND core_attachments.attach_member_id IN (' . $membersIds . ')';
            }


            $whereT = array();
            $joinsT = array();

            $findInPosts = ' AND ' . \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('queued', array('0'));
            $joinsT[] = array(
                                'select'    => 'forums_posts.*',
                                'from'      => 'forums_posts',
                                'where'     => array("forums_posts.pid=core_attachments_map.id2" . $findInPosts),
                        );

            $findInTopics = ' AND ' . \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('approved', array('1'));
            $joinsT[] = array(
                                'select'    => 'forums_topics.*',
                                'from'      => 'forums_topics',
                                'where'     => array("forums_topics.tid=forums_posts.topic_id" . $findInTopics . $fids . $tids),
                        );

            $select = 'core_attachments.attach_id AS custom_data, core_attachments.*';
            if ($group)
            {
                $select = 'core_attachments.attach_id AS custom_data, COUNT(attach_is_image) as cnt_images, SUM(attach_hits) as summ_attach_hits, core_attachments.*';
            }

            $joinsT[] = array(
                                'select'    => $select,
                                'from'      => 'core_attachments',
                                'where'     => array('core_attachments.attach_is_image=1 AND core_attachments.attach_is_archived=0 AND core_attachments.attach_id=core_attachments_map.attachment_id' . $mids),
                        );              

            $joinsT[] = array(  'select'    => 'core_members.member_id, core_members.member_group_id, core_members.mgroup_others, core_members.name, core_members.members_seo_name',
                                'from'      => 'core_members',
                                'where'     => array('core_attachments.attach_member_id=core_members.member_id' . $mids),
                        );

            $joinsT[] = array(  'select'    => 'core_permission_index.perm_id',
                                'from'      => 'core_permission_index',
                                'where'     => array("core_permission_index.app='forums' AND core_permission_index.perm_type='forum' AND core_permission_index.perm_type_id=forums_topics.forum_id"),
                        );

            $groupT = $group;

            $whereT[] = array(
                "core_attachments_map.location_key='forums_Forums' AND " . 
                \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('perm_view', array_merge(array(\IPS\Member::loggedIn()->member_group_id), array_filter(explode(',', \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->mgroup_others)))) . " OR perm_view='*'" .
                $fids . $tids . $mids
            );

            $table = new \IPS\Helpers\Table\Db(
                'core_attachments_map',
                \IPS\Http\Url::internal('app=core&module=system&controller=nbattachpictures', 'front', 'nbattachpictures'),
                $whereT,
                $groupT
            );

            $table->joins = $joinsT;
            $table->limit = $limit;
            $table->sortBy = $order;
            $table->sortDirection = $sort;

            $table->rowsTemplate = array(\IPS\Theme::i()->getTemplate('plugins', 'core', 'global'), 'nbAttachmentsBlocksRows');

            $table->parsers = array(
                'custom_data' => function( $val, $row )
                {
                    return array(
                        'topic_data' => \IPS\Http\Url::internal("app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id={$row['tid']}", 'front', 'forums_topic', array($row['title_seo'])),
                        'summ_attach_hits' => $row['summ_attach_hits'],
                        'jewel' => $this->attachJewel($row['summ_attach_hits']),
                    );
                },
            );

            return $table;
        }
```

Comment: only need recent 20 attachments

Comment: Searching for explicit values in a comma-separated list in a column is always inefficient..... that's why we try to persuade people to normalise their data tables properly, so that such relations can be searche against an index instead of a full table scan.... even FIND_IN_SET only helps simplify the syntax of such a search, not the slow speed

Comment: Can you speed this up? Do you have some code? I was thinking it needs some kind of limit but this is outside of my wheelhouse

Comment: No, I can't magically speed it up for you..... I can tell you that the bad database design is partly responsible for it being slow in the first place.... properly normalizing the database tables and indexing them properly will speed it up

Comment: database design is by invision power board. https://community.invisionpower.com/    It works fine, I think this is just a poorly written function. I have many attachments and members and as such this query is taking forever, the way it's written

Comment: Searching for values in a column that's a comma-separated list of values never works fine

Comment: I am actually not even using that part of the function.

Comment: It's not inside an if, so it's part of the SQL whether you want it or not.... but dump the SQL that's generated and run an EXPLAIN on it to see how MySQL is executing the query... basic SQL diagnostics 101

Comment: ok, I will run explain. I know about explain, what I don't know how to do is get the php out of the way so I have raw SQL